# How do I output a column with spacing in the csv file with a panda?

Tags: pandas, csv

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

It is a code that edits and combines two csv files.
However, the method of outputting the combined file is different.
What should I do with the same format?

I don't think it'll be read properly because of the spacing even if I do it in the same format, but what should I do in this case?

[image]

Comment: Use bracket. `fare_data[' ata_tax']`

Comment: @Psidom Thank you, but I know that part. However, some are marked as ['asdf'] and the other is marked as .asdf.
I want to know how to write ['asdf'] as .asdf.

Comment: @Psidom I feel a little uncomfortable with the inconsistent type.